# Why does the Angular structural directive *ngIf conflict with the [hidden] DOM property when used within the same HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

Why does `[hidden]` fail (meaning when the "loading" boolean is true, the element is NOT hidden) when used within the same `<div>` element as the `*ngIf` structural directive:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center" [hidden]="loading" *ngIf="messages.length > 0 && pagination">
   <pagination [boundaryLinks]="true" [totalItems]="pagination.totalCount" [(ngModel)]="pagination.pageNumber"
      [itemsPerPage]="pagination.pageSize" (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)" previousText="&lsaquo;"
      nextText="&rsaquo;" firstText="&laquo;" lastText="&raquo;">
   </pagination>
</div>
```

Removing `[hidden]` from the `<div>` containing the `*ngIf`, then placing it in the parent `<div>` works just fine:

```
<div [hidden]="loading">
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" *ngIf="messages.length > 0 && pagination">
      <pagination [boundaryLinks]="true" [totalItems]="pagination.totalCount" [(ngModel)]="pagination.pageNumber"
         [itemsPerPage]="pagination.pageSize" (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)" previousText="&lsaquo;"
         nextText="&rsaquo;" firstText="&laquo;" lastText="&raquo;">
      </pagination>
   </div>
</div>
```

Note: The first question I would ask myself is why not include the "loading" boolean within the `*ngIf` conditional, meaning:

`*ngIf="messages.length > 0 && pagination && loading"`

However, when trying this, it caused an infinite loop with the component's `async` API call.  Removing "loading" from the `*ngIf` conditions resolved this issue.  Based on my review of the ngx-bootstrap component  "Pagination" code in github, it appears that the cause of this is due to removing/re-appearing the `<pagination>` selector directive, which causes the `@Output() pageChanged` to re-emit the `pageChanged`.  So it appears including 'loading' in the `*ngIf` conditionals is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `*ngIf` **remove** the element from the DOM, so you has no confic here.

Your has conflic with `hidden` and `d-flex`.

hidden is really `{ display: none !important; }`, so you can replace your [hidden] by

```
[style.display]="loading?'none':null"
```

Note that if not loading, Angular don't add the attribute `[style.display]` (is the reason to use "null")

Or, as you has class you can use [ngClass]

```
[ngClass]="loading?'d-none':'d-flex justify-content-center'"
```

**Update** (thanks for the advise, James), as d-flex of bootstrap is really `{display_flex!importent}` we need add important! to the "none"

```
[style.display]="loading?'none!important':null"
```

Comment: Eliseo - the [ngClass] worked perfectly!  Thank you!  But using my first body of code in my q above, when replacing [hidden] with [style.display], the pagination continued to show while "loading" was "true" (under the elements tab in Chrome dev tools, the element.style would briefly show display:none crossed out while loading).  It seems odd it would do this - any ideas why?

Comment: @JamesLee, ::glups:: d-flex is `{display:flex!important}` so you need add !important to none `[style.display]="loading?'none!important':null"` -I updated the answer, thanks for the advise-

Comment: @Elisio - Thank you for this enlightenment.  I should have caught this also.  Thanks again!